# Avahi Daemon resolving to wrong host name

Tags: avahi

I am facing issues with avahi's address resolution to my apple airport router.

when I run `avahi-browse -alr`

```
   eth0 IPv4 50-35-10-70.1 AirPort Express        _sleep-proxy._udp    local
   hostname = [AirPort-Express.local]
   address = [169.254.8.180]
   port = [54121]
   txt = []
```

This is the output, but my apple airport's ip address is `192.168.1.21`

When I edited the `/etc/avahi/hosts` file to resolve to this IP address, it works for few minutes and then the address is back to `169.254.8.180`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avahi/+bug/896688